# Flashing pixel on desktop and Kodi

Tags: display

Since today I have lots of pixel flashing on my desktop (under Raspbian and raspberry pi 2 B).
Yesterday everythings were fine, but I was doing some stuff on php and other things ... and today here I am.
The flashing pixels are not always the same pixels : it depends on the window, maybe it depends on the color of the pixel which should be displayed.
In kodi it's the same problem.
There is no problem in non GUI mode.
Any ideas to where it comes from ?

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/stw6uc90q4pnq14/flashing-pixels-raspbian.webm?dl=0) a link to a video showing the problem. Sorry for the low quality of my old webcam.
[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wzs3sbjuu2hywuy/wallpaper-original-picture.jpg?dl=0) is the original picture of the desktop.

Comment: Have you rebooted, what specifically were you doing/trying to do? Have you tried the monitor/TV/HDMI cable/SD card/ with a different system? Can you post or at least link to a video that shows the problem? Please edit your question and include this info.

Comment: The monitor works fine, the HDMI cable too.
With an older version of the .img of mine (I save .img reguraly) there is no problem, so the problem doesn't come from the microSD card (then I restored the last version after this test).
I put link to video and original picture of the desktop as you said. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: My Raspberry Pi running Kodi is also flashing all over the place. It's only started in the last few months too.